# Set-Cookie not working properly in axios call

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, setcookie, httpcookie

**Explanation**

here, I sent one get req to ABC.com/Users/Login using Axios after this I sent a post request to ABC.com/Users/Login with form data and Cookie.

but it does not work properly. It works properly in postmen

**My Code**

```
axios.get('ABC.com/Users/Login')
.then(async response => {

   console.log("call login page");
   let tokenKey = "__RequestVerificationToken";
   let tokenValue = "CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTVXaJ-HWILEtqE_A3bGmDrD-yyKyJPbYK7qrcS9AIzezPo5- 
    tOWmcXs6WgYThZP-5qo1o1XXpalkJDEPnBtnVa7EhaUYbY2XNcANuugyWgkIf3-O2-_f5h7mNu960qGIaM";
   const userName="XYZ";
   const pass="test@123";

   let form=new FormData();
   form.append('UserName', userName);
   form.append('Password', pass);
   form.append([tokenKey], tokenValue);

   headers={
        'Cookie':response.headers['set-cookie'];
   }

   await axios.post('ABC.com/Users/Login', form, 
   { headers: {...form.getHeaders(),...headers}})
   .then(async response => {
        console.log(`Login success in ${userName}`);
        console.log("response",response.data);
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });

}
.catch(error => {
console.log(error);
});
```

In the First Axios call, I got:-

```
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.b02ILwhXMuw=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTXz_0rOkGhY6OXEw3d3vsDNG81V4IaMPfVZm5Hk3_icgp_ToLDG9xKu2mcM1VtEOMnSCktfZwG7Dj9_549SUiKht6Yv33pozagGjseFsfXI74wBwu-mMJkzgwfPx3jS4OA; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
Set-Cookie: ABC.Session=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTViv4PoRc%2F7jhjXdtCo4m1GZbcMf60xe9sOva27QUGL0BvT2A2SQZaCmrXlj%2FVL9lTvower%2B1lF87MQVTwDQKAFoEODlnPfWEM6SsrqDa0tomlRynXOtyCROBltiwNI27vo3uo4Y8jEn834lZ4OHYG3; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
```

I Want to set cookie like this :-

```
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.b02ILwhXMuw=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTXz_0rOkGhY6OXEw3d3vsDNG81V4IaMPfVZm5Hk3_icgp_ToLDG9xKu2mcM1VtEOMnSCktfZwG7Dj9_549SUiKht6Yv33pozagGjseFsfXI74wBwu-mMJkzgwfPx3jS4OA; ABC.Session=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTViv4PoRc%2F7jhjXdtCo4m1GZbcMf60xe9sOva27QUGL0BvT2A2SQZaCmrXlj%2FVL9lTvower%2B1lF87MQVTwDQKAFoEODlnPfWEM6SsrqDa0tomlRynXOtyCROBltiwNI27vo3uo4Y8jEn834lZ4OHYG3
```

It works in postmen but not in Axios call. Even I used this also but its not working

```
let cook1 = response.headers['set-cookie'][0].replace(" path=/; samesite=strict; httponly", "");
let cook2 = response.headers['set-cookie'][1].replace("; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly", "");
let mainCookie=cook1 + " " + cook2
// mainCookie .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.b02ILwhXMuw=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTUh3vyphSzebPn04M1GqaH8KdFgWLSBpj5a06HBUhoYBhWdiWJw7Yy5525ZcZ_WblCjF7AzWbhQl2dFbQTwOmzP3K7oa0CLirsSJYkhIG-fHGizaNo-3cf8YdSiECkGhMM; ABC.Session=CfDJ8DF1Ubmz1lpEibYtvvnYRTVEF0LnEGw51HveT2mRMrzmgbHiPWjs8UiPcGcqUpJBhTG1uBSE5NLG8tBwkW1XcJH3OxPcPPsaB30aaRREgroCkO1jw%2BJY6tavDFE0P9RTmk9%2Bf2CTVwaTWYRQgPGam1CWJfODoyCzHwiIdfl8ciJS
headers={
        'Cookie':mainCookie;
}
```

Comment: did you make it work? I have have exact same problem even after I add `withCredentials: true` Postman adds the Cookie automatically but axios doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using *axios*, set `withCredentials` to true.

*Example*:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

then in your *Node*, in cors middleware, set

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    })
);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use Cookies with Axios you need to include the [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) property.

```js
axios.post('ABC.com/Users/Login', form, { withCredentials: true });
```

If it were me I would create a new axios instance and use that one for your calls so that its the same instance of axios for all your api calls.

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
   withCredentials: true
})
axiosInstance.post('ABC.com/Users/Login', form)
```

Answer (score 5):

To use Cookies with Axios, you always need to set the withCredentials property.

Not only when you want to send cookie, but also while receiving, this credentials needs to be set to `true` so that browser can store it.

```
axios.post(ENDPOINT, JSON.stringify(jsonObject), 
{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, withCredentials : true})
```

On the server side, if your frontend and backend origins are not same, make sure you include the `sameSite:'none'` and `secure:true` while sending the cookie:

```
res.cookie('jwt',token, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true , maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000})
res.json(jsonObject)
```

Comment: thank you for writing 'Not only when you want to send cookie, but also while receiving' because this is very not obvious